# PolymerJS POST JSON formatting

Tags: javascript, json, polymer

I am trying to POST using PolymerJS ajax-forms and I encounter a weird JSON format error. Can someone tell me why the  quotes are missing around the keys? The only workaround I can think of is manually constructing the body with the quotes around the keys.

Code Snippet :
How I receive the values (rest are the same with the ids changed):

```
<div>
        <paper-input label="Title" id="course-title" floatingLabel value="{{item.title}}"></paper-input>
    </div>

 <access-core-ajax
              auto = "false"
              url="domain/courses"
              response="{{response}}"
              method="post"
              id="postCourse"
              contentType="application/json"
              headers='{"Accept": "application/json", "Content-Type":"application/json"}',
              body = "{{item}}">

            <template id="get-response-template" repeat="{{item in response.entries}}">
                    <p>Errors</p>
            </template>
        </access-core-ajax>

Polymer('create-new-course-page',{
        domReady: function() {
            console.log("Log: create-new-courses-page - Looks like we are domReady");
        },
        created: function() {
            console.log("Item initialized");
            this.item = {};
            this.data={};
        },
        createNewCourse: function(event) {
            console.log("HERE IS BODY", this.item);
            this.$.postCourse.go();


       }
```

And the JSON is see on the log:

> {
>   title: "WRU",
>   // rest of key & values, where the keys are without the ""
>   }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn the body into a JSON string first. JSON.stringify can help.

```
...
createNewCourse: function(e) {
    this.$.postCourse.body = JSON.stringify(this.item);
    this.$.postCourse.go();
}
```

You may need to remove the body attribute here. You can also remove that auto attribute since by default it is false.